# Import image as planes appears desaturated

Tags: image, color-management

Whenever I import an image as a plane, the image appears to be desaturated as compared to the original. How do I make it more accurate?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of lighting affecting your object. Since its getting hit by a white light, it appears more white and faded. Increase the material's roughness and decrease the specular properties if you want to reduce the effects of lighting on its appearance.

Comment: Note that the wrong colorspace will also affect the result. Images in sRGB will always look wrong in filmic.

Comment: Thanks. I set the specular to 0 and roughness to 1. That got me much closer. Not perfect, but much, much closer.

Comment: Always remember that a buffer represents no single thing in a path tracing engine. Is it normal? Depth? Reflectance? Radiometric emission? Your issue appears to be trying to set a reflectance using the wrong transform as an emission. Reflectances are normalized values representing 0% to 100%. @cegaton’s first response is likely the solution; input buffer management is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't catch the whole problem, so I think it deserve a complete answer.
In fact you have 2 problems here, a light problem and a color management one:

1. Like the name says, image as plane means that it import the image as a mesh (plane), so it's being lit by you scene. To resolve that you need to replace the principled shader added by the addon by an emission shader.
2. Now your shader doesn't interact with the light of your scene but it's still modified by the color management. To change that go to the render properties --> color management --> view transform and change filmic by standard.

Now the image should be the same as the original, but if you have other meshes that you want to render, you shurely don't want to render your scene in standard (RGB clamped).
So for all that I know the only way to have both is to render your scene in filmic without the image, then render the image(s) in standard and combine the 2 layers in post prod (compositor).